# Ubuntu: Fail to open NTFS drives

Tags: 14.04, windows, ntfs

I some times encounter an error when I try to open an `NTFS partition`of my hard disk on Ubuntu Operating System.

> I have installed `Ubuntu` alongside `Windows 8.1`.

**Update:**

when I shut down `windows`, turn on `Ubuntu` and try to open disk it produces an error.

**but**

then I restart my computer. turn on again `Windows` then restart `Windows`. and this time if I turn on `Ubuntu` and open Drives. they easily open, without showing error.

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457224/failed-to-access-windows-8-1-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu-13-10-even-after-disabl)

Comment: This is weird. The problem that the user asks is valid, and as such, pretty much all the needed information is there- that is, if you know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to power management settings on Windows and turn off fast start-up 
That should do the trick for you 
Windows basically keeps the drives in a suspended state and to prevent data loss Ubuntu cannot mount it with rw permissions.

Comment: You can either force the system to mount the drives in rw mode, or you can 'fix' those 'errors' by this command:
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY with sdXY being the partition you are referring to. Open the 'disks' application to find out the X and the Y part.