# "Failed to import images from camera" in Darktable to NTFS drive

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, ntfs, camera, darktable

It started when I was trying to import photos from my camera in Darktable to an NTFS HDD (separate from SSD of OS). This is meant to be a shared drive between my dual boots (Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04). So NTFS doesn't seem to be the issue exactly as I eventually got everything working. But then it stopped again and I was getting the same error ("Failed to import photos from camera"). I restarted and booted Windows, then restarted and booted Ubuntu, now it's working again. It looks like I may need to start up in Windows first every time I want to open Darktable in Ubuntu.

Any explanations?

Comment: Perhaps the NTFS drive got mounted Read-Only, because you hibernated Windows, rather than doing a complete Windows shutdown or drive unmount/remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was the case here: [Ubuntu: Fail to open NTFS drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667725/ubuntu-fail-to-open-ntfs-drives), I turned off Windows 10 Fast Startup and this fixed the issue.