# Ubuntu installations are not displayed when Windows 10 is installed

Tags: 14.04, 15.10, windows-10

I had one drive with `Windows 8.1`, `Ubuntu 15.10` and `Ubuntu 14.04`. The windows was installed on different partition.

Then, I connect a `SSD` drive and install `Windows 10` and format the `Windows 8.1` partition. I have a `USB` with `Ubuntu` installation.

Could anyone tell what should I do in order to get the grub menu back and be able to choose which operating system to start?

Comment: First off, a detailed Canonical answer is NOT required, as this is not Canonical's problem. When you install Windows, Microsoft's bootloader replaces Grub, and completely ignores any non-Windows operating systems.

Comment: You really should do your research. There's already a solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows#88432

Comment: Depends if UEFI or BIOS install(s). And all installs need to be in same boot mode. Best to see details. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/457224/failed-to-access-windows-8-1-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu-13-10-even-after-disabl/457401#457401 . Might help your case..

Answer (score 3):

Basic procedure that I personally would use

1   Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.

2   Press Ctrl-Alt-F1

3   `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

4   `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`

5   `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`

6   `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`

7 `sudo chroot /mnt`

8  `sudo grub-install /dev/sda1`

Comment: I get the following error on step 4 `mount point /mnt/dev does not exists`

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl-Alt-F1 then you need to login as root. Type nano fix.sh and enter

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt1

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt1/dev

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt1/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt1/sys

sudo chroot /mnt1

sudo grub-install /dev/sda1
```

Then save it and type `sh fix.sh`