# Cannot set IPv4 address

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, network-manager, ip

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 in HP EliteDesk 800 G2 SFF, in which Windows 7 is also installed. While wired network connection works well on Windows, it doesn't on DVD-booted Ubuntu. Then I noticed that only IPv6 address is set:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:0f:cf:41:c7:83
          inet6 addr: fe80::4a0f:cfff:fe41:c783/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:972 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:140475 (140.4 KB)  TX bytes:113164 (113.1 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:e1000000-e1020000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:4880 (4.8 KB)  TX bytes:4880 (4.8 KB)
```

I followed [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/330159/535042), but still cannot connect to wired network.

```
$ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
$ sudo service network-manager start
start: Job is already running: network-maneger
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:0f:cf:41:c7:83
          inet6 addr: fe80::4a0f:cfff:fe41:c783/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1776 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:954 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:262483 (262.4 KB)  TX bytes:187146 (187.1 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:e1000000-e1020000
```

What should I do to connect to the network so that I can move on to the Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Probably your network doesn't use DHCP and you'll need to enter the settings manually (IP address, subnet mask, gateway and DNS servers). Please boot into Windows 7 and look at the network settings there.

Comment: Are there any clues here? `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0`

Comment: @user300458 Exactly right. I don't know much about network settings, but found that DHCP is not available with my network (actually, it's not mine but my lab's). I was manually able to set up the Ethernet connection via Network Connections app. Could you post your comment as an answer when you have time so that I can accept it?

Comment: @yudai-nkt, done :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Probably) your network doesn't use DHCP and you need to enter the settings manually (IP address, subnet mask, gateway and DNS servers).

Please boot into Windows 7 and look at the network settings there.